# Total of summed objects of unequal lengths

Tags: summation

I obtained `{1}+{0,2}+{0,0,1}`from a calculation. Now I need to sum these objects and reach `4`. How can I do this? I tried `FlattenAt` command,

```
FlattenAt[{1} + {0, 2} + {0, 0, 1}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}]
```

but it needs to specify the position of each object, while I want a command that sums all of the objects by default because the number of objects is varying.

**Addendum**

In fact I have to obtain a value of $f_k$ according to the formula below
$$`
x_A^i x_B^j= (x_P+A)^i(x_P+B)^j=\sum_{k=0}^{i+j} f_k(i,j,A,B)x^k
$$`
namely $f_k$ consists of coefficients of a binomial.

Comment: That is a very unusual output to get from a calculation. Is this exactly the form of the output?

Comment: @Hugh I get it from a `Sum[CoefficientList[]]` command. Is there an alternative to reach the same result?

Comment: I don't think `Sum` is the correct usage here. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If I have this correct the output from `CoefficientList` is

```
op = {{1}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 1}};
```

You now wish to combine the terms and then add them. Combining the terms can be done by

```
com = Join @@ op
```

> {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1}

You can sum the term by using `Total`

```
Total[com]
```

> 4

Putting everything together gives

```
Total[Join @@ op]
```

> 4

Hope that is clear

Comment: You're right. I can't combine these two commands, it returns `"\"Join@@\" cannot be followed by"`why?

Comment: Can you give a minimum working example of  the code that generates your output?   That will give us something to work on.  Perhaps give us the equation, or an example of one, to which you apply `CoefficientList`

Comment: Thanks see the addendum

Answer (score 1):

```
Total@Catenate@Apply[List, {1} + {0, 2} + {0, 0, 1}]
```

or

```
Map[Total, {1} + {0, 2} + {0, 0, 1}]
```

**Edit:**
The original problem said you got `{1}+{0,2}+{0,0,1}` from a previous calculation.  This is the source of the error, not the ways I gave you to manipulate that expression.  If the expression is something else, you can avoid that.  For example, in a comment you indicate that you actually got `{{1}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 1}}` from the calculation.  Then you can just

```
Total@Catenate@{{1}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both commands return the correct answer but they produce errors `The argument 1 is not a valid Association or a list.` and `Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Total[1]` respectively. Why?

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Thanks a lot. That's right. Another question: the results are as `{1}` not `1` for example. How can I remove the brackets? and why do they appear?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk See edit.

Comment: @Alan Thanks, see my addendum

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk As written, your addendum is actually a separate question. You should create a separate question that elaborates it.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

For your revised question, you can use [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient):

```
SeriesCoefficient[(x+a)^i (x+b)^j, {x, 0, k}, Assumptions -> k>=0]
```

> a^i b^(j - k) Binomial[j, k] Hypergeometric2F1[-i, -k, 1 + j - k, b/a]

**Original answer**

Perhaps you're looking for something like:

```
Total[
    CoefficientList[{1,2x,x^2},x],
    Infinity
]
```

> 4

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a general solution because my list varies each time

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = {1} + {0, 2} + {0, 0, 1}

Plus @@ (Table[expr[[i]], {i, Length[expr]}] // Flatten)
(*4*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily re-define `Plus` for input of lists with unequal lengths:

```
Block[{Plus}, Plus[x__List] := Plus @@ Join[x]; {1} + {0, 2} + {0, 0, 1}]
```

> 4

Comment: Thanks, what does `x` refer to? See the addendum

Comment: @NSR, `x__List`   _is a pattern object that can stand for any sequence of one or more List objects_. See [Blank](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) and [BlankSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html)